# How can I read the content of a data matrix into multiple cells in excel

Tags: excel-2010, barcode, barcode-scanner

I want to use a barcode-scanner (+ data matrix) to perform an input in an existing excel file (*.xlsx). The content of the scanned code should be devidied into two cells, split accoring to a tabulator symbol.

I have generated the following data matrix with the content `Hans<tab>Müller` where `<tab>` equals the decimal character code of 9 in ASCII.

[image]

Scanning the matrix in Notepad++ (focus in Notepad, scanning the matrix) results in the correct result. But if I try the procedure in excel (selecting a cell, scanning the matrix), the input is `HansMüller`. I expected "Hans" in the selected cell and "Müller" in the cell next to the selected one. So, what am I doing wrong?

How can I read the content of a data matrix into multiple cells in excel?

**Update:**
I am using the scanner `ElmiScan ECR14` from elmicron. The website http://codecorp.com/ConfigGuide/?product=CR1400 provides a list of all configuration "codes" (CR1400 equalls ECR14).

If I enable `Control Character Input - Ctrl + Character` as suggested by Brian, Excel reads `HansMÄller` and still ignores the tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting "Hans`<tab>`Mller" in plain old Notepad, and Hans*Mller* in Excel indicating that Excel is interpreting the `<CTRL-I>` as a "let's start typing
in italics now". My system is probably dropping the "ü" because of my U.S. keyboard.

When I copy from Notepad into Excel, however the embedded tab character has the desired result and advances to the next cell. This indicates to me that the scanner is in the default state of "Disable Function Key Mapping" and has interpreted the `<CTRL-I>` you have in the Datamatrix barcode as the keystroke
`<CTRL-I>` instead of the `<TAB>` key.

The solution is to place the scanner into "Enable Function Key Mapping" mode, which is not the default mode by scanning the Function Key Mapping barcodes in your scanner manual.

**EDIT:** So, I've reviewed the website and [1400 Configuration Guide](http://www.codecorp.com/assets/download/D006284-CR1000-CR1400-CR8000--Configuration-Guide.pdf) and needless to say, they disagree. So it looks like there are a few different options for setting keyboard language support, which is where I think the problem lies.

I would start with the [Config Guide](http://www.codecorp.com/assets/download/D006284-CR1000-CR1400-CR8000--Configuration-Guide.pdf) and test modes B4, D3, D2, C3, B2, and B3 in that order.

[image: Screendump from 1400 Configuration Guide PDF]

Then I would move onto the [website based guide](http://codecorp.com/ConfigGuide/?product=CR1400#) and check out each of the following modes just to be sure.

[image: Edited Screendump from 1400 Configuration Website]

The fact that after your previous experiment the "ü" turns into a "Ä" tells me we are on the right track. One of these settings should produce an ASCII `<TAB>` keyboard character for Excel. If none of these works, I would contact technical support at [Elmicron](http://elmicron.de/de/kontakt.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Brian. Somehow it is still not working. I will add more information into my question.

Comment: Hmm.. This fixed it for my Symbol DS6707. Lemme check the website. Thanks for updating the question.

Comment: Thank you again for your long answer. It seemed to be a Elmicon 'feature'. The solution was to select "Keyboard Mapping for Apple", which fixed the problem on Linux and Windows :-/

Comment: Ah, the old featuroo. Gets us every time.